# Integration of Cucumber.js and WebStorm 2016

Tags: cucumber, webstorm, cucumberjs

Apparently only up to Cucumber.js 1.3.1 is all fine in WebStorm, but when moving to 2.0 the plugin is not working correctly (still generates the step binding the old way) and once fixed the runner says "Test framework quit unexpectedly" even if the feature tests all pass.

Any suggestion?

Comment: CucumberJS 2.0 is still under construction. I would say that - if there hasn't been a ticket raised with them already - you create a ticket on their [bug tracker for WebStorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB).

They'll get round to fixing any issues that you come across

Comment: I'm coming across the same issues, I might raise a note with them. (I updated to get access to the Cucumber Expressions)

Comment: Thank you. i raised a ticket as well.